# How to sort Varchar Date in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table schema (table Name Stock)

**Field**

```
Date Datetime
```

If `Date` having datatype is `Datetime` then SQL Server sorts the date in well/perfect order.  See Below Example.

```
select date from stock order by date
```

Then result is:

```
Date(yyyy/MM/dd)
2010-04-02 00:00:00.000
2011-02-02 00:00:00.000
2011-02-03 00:00:00.000
2011-02-03 00:00:00.000
```

But if I am going to sort the same by casting varchar than it will be ultimately create problem and the problem is it will not sort date by date order as it is now casting in Varchar.

Look at example below:

```
select date = convert(varchar, date, 103) from stock order by date
```

Then result is:

```
Date(dd/MM/yyyy)
02/02/2011
02/04/2010
03/02/2011
03/02/2011
```

You can see second query’s result that it will not sort date in order as because it is now not in datetime datatype. It is casting as varchar or you can say it as string.

Now come to the point that:

If I want to sort date which is casting in varchar order by date than how to do it?.

Comment: @marc_s, Thanks, but read my last line of my question please.

Comment: @marc_s, Do you mean store date as datatype date, Oh! come on man SQL-Server-2000 doesn't have data type date.

Comment: no, but SQL Server 2000 **does have** a datatype `DATETIME` - use that !!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you're doing is converting a `varchar` to a `varchar` and then sorting by that... you're not sorting by date!

```
convert(varchar, date, 103)
       *********
```

This type here is what you convert your value into - you're converting **into a `varchar`** - of course it won't sort by date then!

Try this instead:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, date, 103) 
FROM dbo.Stock 
ORDER BY CONVERT(DATETIME, date, 103)
```

**NOW** you're actually converting your `varchar` column `date` to a `DATETIME` value, and sorting on that resulting `DATETIME` - and now you get the output:

```
2010-04-02 00:00:00.000
2011-02-02 00:00:00.000
2011-02-03 00:00:00.000
2011-02-03 00:00:00.000
```

**Update:** if you need another formatting, you can of course convert your `DATETIME` again, back into a `VARCHAR` using `CONVERT` with a different style:

Read all about what styles are supported in [MSDN CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms187928.aspx)

```
SELECT 
    date = CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(DATETIME, date, 103), 103)  -- convert back to VARCHAR
FROM 
    dbo.Stock 
ORDER BY 
    CONVERT(DATETIME, date, 103)   -- sort by the DATETIME !
```

and then you get this output:

```
02/04/2010
02/02/2011
03/02/2011
03/02/2011
```

Just make sure to sort on the **`DATETIME`** value! (not on a string representation of your `DATETIME`)

And as I said: if you store your dates as DATETIME from the beginning, you'll save yourself a lot of those conversion back and forth!!

Comment: Yes it's tried before me but there is a problem and problem is that it will return in yyyy/MM/dd  Format where as my requirement is of dd/MM/yyyy Format what You think about that?

Comment: Yes you are right and your formula is works but little problem is that there no column name display hence kindly edit your code's second line to date=CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(DATETIME, date, 103), 103)  -- convert back to VARCHAR

Answer (score 1):

You can use sub query as follows

```
select convert(varchar,date,103) date from (select date from stock order by date)p
```

Comment: It's throw error like :"Server: Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 58
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, and subqueries, unless TOP is also specified."

Answer (score 0):

this one worked for me:

```
SELECT date FROM stock ORDER BY CAST(date AS DATE)
```